# Calendar in hidden div

Tags: javascript, css, calendar, position, hidden

I'm using a JavaScript calendar 3 times in one form. The first instance works just like it should. the second and third ones are both in hidden divs that show onclick. The calendar pops up in the top left corner of the page for those two. How do I get it to be positioned like it should?

```
    <div id="form_container">
    <form  method="post" action="index.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Day One</legend>
            <li id="li_7" >
            <label class="description" for="d1_date">Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="d1_date" id="d1_date" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['d1_date'])){ echo $_GET['d1_date']; }else{ echo "";}?>" class="event_search_date_input" /> 
            </li>   
            <a class="add_day_link" onclick="document.getElementById('day_two_div').style.display='';position='relative';return false;" 
            href="" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">Plan the next day...</a>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="day_two_div" style="display:none;"> 
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Day Two</legend>
            <li id="li_14" >
            <label class="description" for="d2_date">Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="d2_date" id="d2_date" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['d2_date'])){ echo $_GET['d2_date']; }else{ echo "";}?>" class="event_search_date_input" /> 
            </li>   
            <a class="add_day_link" onclick="document.getElementById('day_three_div').style.display='';return false;" 
            href="" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;">Plan the next day...</a>
        </fieldset>
    </div><!-- close day_two_div -->    
            <li class="buttons">
                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form> 
    </div><!-- close formContainer -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/datepickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new datepickr('d1_date', {
            'dateFormat': 'Y-m-d'
        });
        new datepickr('d2_date', {
            'dateFormat': 'Y-m-d'
        });
        new datepickr('d3_date', {
            'dateFormat': 'Y-m-d'
        });
    </script>
```

This is the code that I feel like needs to be corrected?

```
    var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
    calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dd = document.createElement("div");  
dd.addClass("calendar");  
dd.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100;';  
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];  
b.appendChild(dd);
```

This is just a transcription of what you described.
Ideas apply anyways.
If you want more specific code, describe your situation in more detail and post your complete code -- things like what variables are used can not be seen otherwise